# Как вставить картинку внутрь инпута как placeholder?

Tags: вёрстка

Решил сделать себе челлендж 1день- 1проект. В общем я тренируюсь.

фрагмент от макета:
[image: фрагмент от макета]

как сделать такие инпуты? иконка есть с fontawesome но можно предложить и свой вариант

Comment: <div> <картинка> <input> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой пример

```css
input#search{
 background-image: url('https://media.cdnandroid.com/item_images/1073704/imagen-x-icon-changer-customize-app-icon-shortcut-0big.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 text-indent: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

input#search:focus{
 /*background-image: none;*//*Чтобы картинка исчезала*/
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" autocomplete="off" onblur="this.placeholder='search'"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант)

Comment: На здоровье!!!)