# Как это сверстать

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не понимаю как разместить иконки в инпуте. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355198/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-placeholder/1355210#1355210) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-input)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление иконки в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897079/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-input)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.icon-input {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/account-avatar-profile-human-man-user-30448.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: top 0 right 8px;
  padding-right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<input class="icon-input" type="text">
```

Comment: Да у меня так же получается. Но нужно чтобы картинка не до конца вправо уходила, как показано на скрине

Comment: меняй первое значение в  background-position, поправил ответ - чекай там

Comment: Не 95%, а right 1em.

Comment: первое по x, второе по y. Следовательно, right 1em это справа к краю и сверху 1em.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="pass">
  <div class="text_errors"></div>
  <input id="pass"  type="password">
  <img src="" alt="icon">
</label>
```

Как-то так будет правильно... ну или там через background-img к обёртке

Comment: Стилей явно не хватает.